# distance point plane

Tags: geometry

I have to prove this:
$$d(P,\pi) = \frac{|ax+by+cz+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
normal vector: $ n = (a,b,c)$

$P(x,y,z)$ a generic point of the plane $P'(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

$PP' = (x-x_0)i + (y-y_0)j+ (z-z_0)k$

$$d(P,pi)  = \| PP'\|\times\cos\theta= \frac{\|n\| \|PP'\|\cos\theta}{\|n\|}= \frac{(n PP')}{\|n\|}$$
defining $d$, I get
$$d(P,\pi)  = \frac{ax+by+cz+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
but I don't see the absolute value, how should I get it?

thanks

Comment: Well, you could have $ax+by+cz+d<0$ so you for sure need the absolute value

Comment: If absolute value dropped, the formula defines the two (distinct) "sides" of the plane in 3-space. When formula + it's one side, formula - it's other side. (Of course some convention must be set up to say which is which...)

Comment: maybe i'm understanding, but when i prove this to my professor, can I just say that to avoid a negative distance i have to add absolute value? thanks

Comment: @GiovanniCastellano Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to take the absolute value since the distance is defined as a positive value.

As an alternative derivation, the line orthogonal to the plane and passing through $P'$ has equation

- $(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t(a,b,c)$

the intersection $Q$ with the plane is given by

$$a(x_0+ta)+b(y_0+tb)+c(z_0+ct)+d=0 \implies t=-\frac{ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

therefore the distance squared $PQ^2$ is

$$PQ^2=t^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=\frac{(ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\implies PQ=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Comment: thanks, what $t$ represent? could you explicit the distance $PQ$?

Comment: @GiovanniCastellano $t$ is a real parameter for the parametric form of the line. The distance squared is $$QP^2=(Q-P)\cdot (Q-P)=(at.bt,ct)\cdot (at,bt,ct)$$

Comment: sorry, i don't understand this :(

Comment: @GiovanniCastellano We need to apply Pythagoras between the points $ P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $Q=(x_0+ta,y_0+tb,z_0+tc)$.